# sass Error: Undefined variable: $sidebar-spacing-horizontal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css, sass

I purchased the learnplus theme from themeforest and tried to build it. However while building i am constantly getting this error:

```
    node_modules/adminplus/src/sass/sidebar-components/_card.scss
    Error: Undefined variable: "$sidebar-spacing-horizontal".
    on line 3 of node_modules/adminplus/src/sass/sidebar-components/_card.scss
>>      margin-bottom: $sidebar-spacing-horizontal;
-----------------^
```

I tried to search a lot but was in vain as i am a total noob with no understanding about Sass. I assume its something to do with ROR syntax file which is compiled into .css.

Can someone help me with the issue? I am not understanding how to resolve this error? Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Hi All, there was a slight confusion with the bootstrap-layout version. $sidebar-spacing-horizontal variable has been depricated in bootstrap-layout@1.0.0-alpha.10. I changed it to bootstrap-layout@1.0.0-alpha.5 and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with that theme, but whenever you see some variable declarations of the theme, you can make something like this - `$sidebar-spacing-horizontal: 20px;`. After that you can try to compile again.

Comment: thanks a lot. Also aforementioned, there is substantial changes in the naming convention of the two versions.

Comment: I glad that I helped ;)